# Nginx Config - Apple Mac, localhost binding

Tags: macos, nginx

simple(ish) Nginx config containing this:

```
server {
    listen      127.0.0.2:7999; 
    server_name site2;

    location / {
        root   ../project_html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to bind to a localhost IP (but not 127.0.0.1): I get

```
[emerg] bind() to 127.2.0.0:7999 failed (49: Can't assign requested address)
```

for all IPs other than 127.0.0.1. Struggling to find a good reason why? (Online people seem to have this problem when the network adapter has just come up, but this doesn't seem to be the case).

*I am on an Apple, El Capitan with Nginx via homebrew if that helps. I also realise the problem with root inside of location, but this is my minimal non-working example (sorry!)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I didn't realise i asked this here, but I did - and I now know the answer! The issue is nothing to do with Nginx, but everything to do with Apple: For some reason, Apple Mac's only know about 127.0.0.1 and not everything: The solution is to add aliases onto the network stack with the following:

`sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.2.0.1`

It doesn't seem to add multiple times so calling on every run doesn't 'damage' the system by adding the same alias over and over, but you can call multiple times with different aliases.

I suspect its a fundamental decision in the networking stack.